# Lua objects not just tables?

Tags: oop, lua

I am very new to Lua and am trying to write a short script using the [Aseprite API](https://github.com/aseprite/api).
The API uses the [`Image`](https://github.com/aseprite/api/blob/master/api/image.md#image) object to represent images.

My understanding of OOP in Lua is that everything is simply a table. There are no classes or objects, just functions that return tables.

I thought, then that I would be able to view all the attributes of an [`Image`](https://github.com/aseprite/api/blob/master/api/image.md#image) object just iterating through it using `pairs(table)`.

```lua
-- `image` is and Image object
for attribute, value in pairs(image) do
   app.alert(k..": "..v) -- creates an alert window in the Aseprite app
end
```

I would expect this to show me each attribute and method name available for use. Instead, I just get an error:

```
lua:2: bad argument #1 to 'for iterator' (table expected, got ImageObj)
```

How is it possible that this is not just a table? What is this? How might I print all attributes and method names available to me in this 'object'?

Comment: Lua also has `userdata` https://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html you can make a table with a list of the attribute names, and get the value from `image` using them in a for loop

Comment: The variable `image` is of type `userdata`—or, more specifically, it is an `ImageObj` type. One can iterate through a userdata type if it has a `__pairs` metamethod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Lua Reference Manual, like on page 1-2

> There are eight basic types in Lua: nil, boolean, number, string,
> function, **userdata**, thread, and table.
>
> The type userdata is provided to allow arbitrary C data to be stored
> in Lua variables. A userdata value represents a block of raw memory.
> There are two kinds of userdata: full userdata, which is an object
> with a block of memory managed by Lua, and light userdata, which is
> simply a C pointer value. Userdata has no predefined operations in
> Lua, except assignment and identity test. By using metatables, the
> programmer can define operations for full userdata values (see §2.4).
> Userdata values cannot be created or modified in Lua, only through the
> C API. This guarantees the integrity of data owned by the host program
> and C libraries.

So no, there is not just tables.

> How might I print all attributes and method names available to me in
> this 'object'?

image is a `ImageObj`, but `Image` should be a table that provides functions that you can use on ImageObjs.

Try `for k,v in pairs(Image) do print(k,v) end`

Or simply refer to the API documentation.

https://github.com/aseprite/api/blob/master/api/image.md#image